# __persistence__ NoMethodError

Tags: jruby, jruby-java-interop

I'm mocking a java interface in rspec

```
clock = ClockInterface.new
clock.should_receive(:currentTime)
```

When I run rspec everything works fine but I see a warning which directs me to the following

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Persistence

When I attempt to set

```
ClockInterface.__persistence__ = true
```

I get a NoMethodError. I'm using jruby 1.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClockInterface` is an interface rather than a class, and doesn’t have the `__persistent__` method, unlike classes for which that method gets added through their proxy.

To get your test to work properly, you should instead use:

```
clock = mock(ClockInterface)
clock.should_receive(:currentTime)
```